# Django not finding custom user model in settings when migrating

Tags: python, django

I've created a custom `User` model in models.py:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    pass
```

Then, I've set `AUTH_USER_MODEL` to that model, in settings.py:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'workoutcal.User'
```

workoutcal is included in `INSTALLED_APPS`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'workoutcal',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework_mongoengine',
]
```

And I've included this in admin.py:

```
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

Then, I've ran `makemigrations` and `migrate`, and on the latter, I get this long error traceback:

```
(workout) sahands-mbp:workout sahandzarrinkoub$ python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions, workoutcal
Running migrations:
  Applying admin.0001_initial...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 356, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 204, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 115, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 145, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 244, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 129, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/models.py", line 97, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.create_model(model)
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 254, in create_model
    definition, extra_params = self.column_sql(model, field)
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 144, in column_sql
    db_params = field.db_parameters(connection=self.connection)
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 994, in db_parameters
    return {"type": self.db_type(connection), "check": self.db_check(connection)}
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 991, in db_type
    return self.target_field.rel_db_type(connection=connection)
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 909, in target_field
    return self.foreign_related_fields[0]
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 653, in foreign_related_fields
    return tuple(rhs_field for lhs_field, rhs_field in self.related_fields if rhs_field)
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 640, in related_fields
    self._related_fields = self.resolve_related_fields()
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 625, in resolve_related_fields
    raise ValueError('Related model %r cannot be resolved' % self.remote_field.model)
ValueError: Related model 'workoutcal.User' cannot be resolved
```

It seems to me like the error stems from the admin.0001_initial migration. When I look into the python file of that migration, I find this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

import django.contrib.admin.models
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        migrations.swappable_dependency(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
        ('contenttypes', '__first__'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='LogEntry',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(verbose_name='ID', serialize=False, auto_created=True, primary_key=True)),
                ('action_time', models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name='action time')),
                ('object_id', models.TextField(null=True, verbose_name='object id', blank=True)),
                ('object_repr', models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='object repr')),
                ('action_flag', models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(verbose_name='action flag')),
                ('change_message', models.TextField(verbose_name='change message', blank=True)),
                ('content_type', models.ForeignKey(
                    to_field='id',
                    on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                    blank=True, null=True,
                    to='contenttypes.ContentType',
                    verbose_name='content type',
                )),
                ('user', models.ForeignKey(
                    to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                    verbose_name='user',
                )),
            ],
            options={
                'ordering': ('-action_time',),
                'db_table': 'django_admin_log',
                'verbose_name': 'log entry',
                'verbose_name_plural': 'log entries',
            },
            bases=(models.Model,),
            managers=[
                ('objects', django.contrib.admin.models.LogEntryManager()),
            ],
        ),
    ]
```

What is the reason for my error, and how do I solve it?

EDIT: Alasdair asked whether or not my workoutcal app has migrations. It does. The migrations-folder contains three python-files:

**__init__.py**

```
# empty
```

**0001_initial.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Generated by Django 1.11.5 on 2017-09-11 17:20
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Person',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('name', models.CharField(max_length=200)),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Workout',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('date', models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='workout date')),
                ('person', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='workoutcal.Person')),
            ],
        ),
    ]
```

**0002_auto_20171212_1445**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Generated by Django 1.11.5 on 2017-12-12 14:45
from __future__ import unicode_literals

import django.contrib.auth.models
import django.contrib.auth.validators
from django.db import migrations, models
import django.utils.timezone


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('auth', '0008_alter_user_username_max_length'),
        ('workoutcal', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='User',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('password', models.CharField(max_length=128, verbose_name='password')),
                ('last_login', models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='last login')),
                ('is_superuser', models.BooleanField(default=False, help_text='Designates that this user has all permissions without explicitly assigning them.', verbose_name='superuser status')),
                ('username', models.CharField(error_messages={'unique': 'A user with that username already exists.'}, help_text='Required. 150 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only.', max_length=150, unique=True, validators=[django.contrib.auth.validators.UnicodeUsernameValidator()], verbose_name='username')),
                ('first_name', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=30, verbose_name='first name')),
                ('last_name', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=30, verbose_name='last name')),
                ('email', models.EmailField(blank=True, max_length=254, verbose_name='email address')),
                ('is_staff', models.BooleanField(default=False, help_text='Designates whether the user can log into this admin site.', verbose_name='staff status')),
                ('is_active', models.BooleanField(default=True, help_text='Designates whether this user should be treated as active. Unselect this instead of deleting accounts.', verbose_name='active')),
                ('date_joined', models.DateTimeField(default=django.utils.timezone.now, verbose_name='date joined')),
                ('groups', models.ManyToManyField(blank=True, help_text='The groups this user belongs to. A user will get all permissions granted to each of their groups.', related_name='user_set', related_query_name='user', to='auth.Group', verbose_name='groups')),
                ('user_permissions', models.ManyToManyField(blank=True, help_text='Specific permissions for this user.', related_name='user_set', related_query_name='user', to='auth.Permission', verbose_name='user permissions')),
            ],
            options={
                'verbose_name': 'user',
                'verbose_name_plural': 'users',
                'abstract': False,
            },
            managers=[
                ('objects', django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager()),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.RemoveField(
            model_name='workout',
            name='person',
        ),
        migrations.DeleteModel(
            name='Person',
        ),
        migrations.DeleteModel(
            name='Workout',
        ),
    ]
```

Comment: Does your `workoutcal` app have migrations? If not, run `python manage.py makemigrations workoutcal`.

Comment: If I run your command, I get:
`$ python manage.py makemigrations workoutcal
No changes detected in app 'workoutcal'`

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that question. How do I check if it does? What does it mean to "have migrations"?

Comment: Does your `workoutcal` app have a `migrations` folder, and if so, what does it contain?

Comment: It does. I've listed them in an edit to my question.

Comment: If you set `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'workoutcal.User'` after creating the database it can cause problems. If you don't have any important data in the db, then try dropping the database, deleting the migrations from the app, then re-running `makemigrations` and `migrate`.

Comment: Did what you said and successfully ran `makemigrations` and `migrate` without errors.

Comment: Great, glad it worked :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's very difficult to change `AUTH_USER_MODEL` after your project has been started. [See the note in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#changing-to-a-custom-user-model-mid-project).

If you don't have any important data in the db, I would drop the database, deleting the migrations from the `workoutcal` app, then re-run `makemigrations` and `migrate`.